# Can I use commas here to avoid confusion?

Tags: grammar

> When you turn on the radio while the house is quiet **,** or you use the radio in your car, you have several choices of music to listen to. (The bold-faced comma, first one)

Ok from the content, it is obvious that "you use the radio in you car" is an alternative to "when you turn the radio while the house is quiet", but grammatical I am not sure if anyone would confuse it as another case of "while", like "when you turn on the radio while you use the radio in your car".

Is it absolutely necessary to repeat **when** after  **or**?

Answer (score 1):

> When you turn on the radio while the house is quiet, or you use the radio in your car, you have several choices of music to listen to.

That version is correct and perfectly understandable. You could also say, e.g.

> When you turn on the radio while the house is quiet or use the radio in your car you have several choices of music to listen to.

I have omitted the second 'you'. Note that some people may prefer a comma after 'car'. Personally I don't find any commas to be necessary.

Comment: The first one has the possibility of being confusing. People might think "you use the radio.." is part of the "while" clause and not the "when" clause.

Comment: @Doeser - I don't think so. I find it almost impossible to read it that way. Even if you try to punctuate it to force that interpretation I don't think you could. Perhaps you'd like to try?

Comment: Ok what about "when you turn on the radio while the house is quiet or you are driving to work or school in your car, you have several choices of musics to listen to" (here the intended idea is that you turn on radio in two different occasions. How do you differentiate between this one and the one I gave in my question?)

Comment: I still don't get it. Unless your car is inside your house, surely they have to be two different occasions (?)

Comment: Sorry if my intention of making a different sentence isn't clear to you. In my original question, there are two "when" cases.(when you turn on the radio while you house is quiet and when you use it inside your car). In my comment question, the action of turning on radio is common to both "while the house is quiet" and while you are driving to work".

Comment: Does whether the car is inside the house affect which of "when" and "while" the "or" clause follows?

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it now. You are suggesting the possibility, *When you turn on the radio while the house is quiet  or while you use the radio in your car...*',  Maybe that would confuse some translation software but I can't imagine a native speaker interpreting it that way.  Don't forget that fluent readers scan a sentence very quickly and are able to extract the meaning without thinking about it. Only 'garden path' sentences or those with many long and complicated subclauses tend to cause any real problems.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But how does a native speaker identify "you use the radio in your car" with "when" not "while" so quickly? (For me, I would think only when the person turn on the radio in his car, can he have several choices of music.)

Comment: I am referring to my comment question : **when you turn on the radio while the house is quiet, or you are driving to school, you have several choices of music to listen to**.